# Output is different, is there any time lag for hibernate commands to get executed

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

My Project class -

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    private Integer projectId;

    private String projectName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

My Employee class -

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Integer employeeId;
    private String employeeName;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Project> projects;
}
```

My main class -

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Employee employee1 = new Employee();
employee1.setEmployeeId(1);
employee1.setEmployeeName("Harry");
Employee employee2 = new Employee();
employee2.setEmployeeId(2);
employee2.setEmployeeName("Ron");

Project project1 = new Project();
project1.setProjectId(3);
project1.setProjectName("ABC");
Project project2 = new Project();
project2.setProjectId(4);
project2.setProjectName("DEF");

List<Project> projectList = new ArrayList<>();
projectList.add(project1);
projectList.add(project2);
employee1.setProjects(projectList);

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

session.save(employee1);
session.save(employee2);
session.save(project1);
session.save(project2);

transaction.commit();

Project project3 = session.get(Project.class, 3);
System.out.println(project3.getProjectId() + " " + project3.getProjectName());
for(Employee employee : project3.getEmployees()){
       System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeId()+" "+ employee.getEmployeeName());
}

session.close();
sessionFactory.close();
```

On running the above code, employee1, employee2, project1, project2 are successfully saved into the database but I get a `NullPointerException` with `project3.getEmployees()`.

But the next time I run the code (with all the save commands commented), `project3.getEmployees()` is not null and contains Employee(employeeId=1, employeeName="Harry").

Is there any time lag because of which the first time I get a `NullPointerException` with `project3.getEmployees()`?

Note - `project3.getProjectId()` and `project3.getProjectName()` don't return null in either of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually manage the relationship properly between `Project` and `Employee` before they are saved to DB. To facilitate it , you can create an instance method on `Employee` to encapsulate such logic rather than directly set the employee 's project list.

```java
public class Employee {
    
    public void addProject(Project project){
        this.projects.add(project);
        project.getEmployees().add(this);
    }
}
```

And manage their relationships by :

```java
employee1.addProject(project1);
employee1.addProject(project2);
```

Of course you can do it in other way round , which add an employee to a project :

```java
public class Project {
    
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee){
        this.employees.add(employee);
        employee.getProjects().add(this);
    }
}
```

And manage their relationship by :

```
project1.addEmployee(employee1);
project2.addEmployee(employee1);
```

When you get `project3` , it just return you the `project1` instance from the `Session` as both `project1` and `project3` refer to the same ID. Since you do not manage `project1` 's employees properly before , it has NULL employees list and hence you get `NullPointerException`.

The time when you execute it again , `project3` is loaded from the DB which hibernate already help to manage their relationship automatically and hence you do not get `NullPointerException`

If you do want to manage the relationship by yourself, you can call `session.refresh(employee1)` after the transaction is commit to force hibernate to refresh its latest state from the DB which should not solve the `NullPointerException` :

```java
....
transaction.commit();
session.refresh(project1);

Project project3 = session.get(Project.class, 3);
System.out.println(project3.getProjectId() + " " + project3.getProjectName());
for(Employee employee : project3.getEmployees()){
       System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeId()+" "+ employee.getEmployeeName());
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Just one thing, when you say 'When you get project3 , it just return you the project1 instance from the Session as both project1 and project3 refer to the same ID', are you referring to the cache?

Comment: you are right . As the session is still not closed, it still cache the object that are managed by it before (i.e project1) . The session is actually a cache which is called the 1st-level cache in hibernate.